# Conditional inside `printf` statement

Tags: c, printf, text-formatting

Is there a way to shorten this:

```
if (a > 0)
    printf("%d", a);
else
    printf("%d", -a);
```

I mean, is there a way to write all this inside one `printf` with the `?` operator?

Comment: `printf("%d\n", ((a>0)-(a<0))*a);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
printf("%d", (a > 0? a: -a));
```

Input/Output:

```
 5 -> 5
-5 -> 5
```

A little test program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

    int a = -5, b = 5;

    printf("%d\n", (a > 0? a: -a));
    printf("%d\n", (b > 0? b: -b));

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: and what if i have text if it's true and integer when it's false?

Comment: @AnDrOiD What do you mean with: `if i have text`? If you have a `char []` then the placeholder is false! Also what should `integer when it's false` mean?

Comment: @AnDrOiD: then you also need different *format strings*, because you cannot use `%d` with a string. (Which is still possible but may get unreadable very fast.)

Answer (score 3):

Use the ternary operator.

```
printf("%d\n",(a>0) ? a:-a);
```

If the condition is `true`, then after the `?` will be executed. Otherwise, after the `:` will be executed.

Answer (score 2):

It looks that you want to obtain an [absolute value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value). For `int` type you might use [`abs()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/abs) function from `<stdlib.h>` header for such purpose:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int a;

    a = 3;
    printf("%d\n", abs(a));

    a = -3;
    printf("%d\n", abs(a));

    return 0;
}
```

There are also `labs()` for `llabs()` (C99) for `long int` and `long long int` types respectively as well as for floating-point types e.g. [`fabs()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fabs) from `<math.h>`.